# transfer data from mysql to redis and redis configuration

Tags: linux, database, redis, centos, nosql

I am new in redis

I need some information about it like :

can I change the unicode of it to utf 8

how can transfer one table of mysql to redis (with hmset features) (manual is too hard and I need some information about automating it by tools and ...)

and I want to request a server but how much RAM is needed for redis (how to estimate RAM)

Comment: How big is Mysql table ?
What Mysql you are using ?
How big is the Redis Cluster ?

Comment: mysql table included 350000 row - I use mysql to only save reporting data of banking transaction in our company

Comment: In that case I would recommend writing a NodeJS script which will query database and make a JSON out of the result and save each entry 1 by 1 to Redis. 
I would also recommend creating at least 3 node redis cluster with save to disk and low balance it before carry out any transfers

Comment: can we used "hset"(data list) for transfer data to redis ? i mean did a tools or script exist for this purpose ?

Comment: I am not sure. I usually write that kind of code myself and run it one by one till for testing purpose and once everything work I run it overnight in a way so my CPU/Memory dont burst or I dont overload the system.

Comment: by the way ,thank you very much for your attention to my question